Do you automate testing of the responsiveness of UI app?
I agree that responsiveness of the UI app is important and must be tested. But, do you think, we should automate responsive tests of UI using Selenium?

The short answer is: yes, it should be automated. However, we have to think strategically so as not to waste our most precious resource, time. There are tools that map where access to your website is coming from, if only 5% of accesses are from mobile devices, is it worth facing the complexity of doing automation just to ensure that these 5% have access to the website in the expected way? Or can we do some manual testing just to confirm that it's working normally and leave the automation just for the web? Understand, it's a fine line, it must be discussed with the team to reach a conclusion.

The straight answer will be YES.
But this depends on time, budget and priority. If your application is widely used on desktop view and only exceptional user uses it on mobile/tablet view then the question is should you be investing your time and resources for those unique users? if the answer is yes, then your automation script must support mobile/tablet view too.
